# Additionally filter buttons won´t update the URL hash (see my JSFIDDLE)

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, jquery-bbq

sadly i am not that good with JS to find out what is wrong
I am trying like it says on this page

```
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/hash-history.html#filter=*&sortAscending=true
```

If i click on the first filter the result is ok but as soon as i select another filter the filter before gets removed by the 2nd.

Please see my Fiddle here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/5Quw8/
```

With best regards,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot the `<div id="options">` bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Quw8/1/